# How to add a new participant to existing conversation in mailboxer?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, messaging, mailboxer

I would like to add a new participant(not `current_user`) to one of my conversations.

I created a conversation with

```
receipt = user1.send_message([user2, user3], 'body', 'subject'])
user2.reply_to_conversation(receipt.conversation, 'body')
```

I would like as a `user3` to add new `user4` to the one of his conversations.
Something like this.

```
user3.invite_to_conversation(receipt.conversation)
receipt.conversation.participants => [user1, user2, user3, user4]
```

I wasn't able to find a helpfull method in documentation and source code.

Documentation:
https://github.com/mailboxer/mailboxer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just found a method in [source code](https://github.com/mailboxer/mailboxer/blob/3e148858879110c3258b46152b11e5bfc514dc04/app/models/mailboxer/conversation.rb#L149), which does the job.

```
conversation.add_participant(user4)
```